# Varrer array via javascript e remover objetos duplicados com Map

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Estou percorrendo o seguinte JSON:

```
[
    {
        "amount": 6,
        "codes": [
            "BRCH",
            "ARSI",
            "ENSI"
        ]
    },
    {
        "amount": 6,
        "codes": [
            "BRCH",
            "ARSI",
            "ENSI"
        ]
    },
        {
        "amount": 6,
        "codes": [
            "BRCH",
            "ARSI",
            "ENSI"
        ]
    },
    {
        "amount": 2,
        "codes": [
            "BRSI",
            "ARSI"
        ]
    },
        {
        "amount": 2,
        "codes": [
            "BRSI",
            "ARSI"
        ]
    }
]
```

Pois bem, estou utilizando a função Map do javascript para percorrer ele e remover os itens repetidos e para isso verifico se a quantidade e os códigos são iguais:

```
let unique = new Map(itemsToClear.map(obj => [obj.amount, obj] && [obj.options.codes, obj]));
const uniques = Array.from(unique.values());
```

Porém, ao utilizar essa forma ele não está conseguindo varrer o array de códigos, há uma forma de realizar essa ação?

Comment: "*pois contem muitos dados lixo e desnecessários*", isso é um excelente sinal de que você deveria elaborar um [mcve] eliminando todo esse ruído.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! Atualizei a questão minimalizando pra ficar mais claro.

Comment: se quer remover duplicados poderia deveria criar um novo array só com os itens únicos, adicionando os itens dentro do map, que tal?

Comment: Como poderia montar então? Que estou tentando realizar isso mesmo com a função Array.from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode comparar se 2 objectos "são iguais" se converter ambos para uma string JSON.

```js
const array = [
    {
        "amount": 6,
        "codes": ["BRCH", "ARSI", "ENSI"]
    },
    {
        "amount": 6,
        "codes": ["BRCH", "ARSI", "ENSI"]
    },
    {
        "amount": 6,
        "codes": ["BRCH", "ARSI", "ENSI"]
    },
    {
        "amount": 2,
        "codes": ["BRSI", "ARSI"]
    },
    {
        "amount": 2,
        "codes": ["BRSI", "ARSI"]
    }
];

const result = array
    .map(e => JSON.stringify(e))
    .reduce((acc, cur) => (acc.includes(cur) || acc.push(cur), acc), [])
    .map(e => JSON.parse(e));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Não acho que usar `JSON.stringify` para esse tipo de uso seja algo seguro, uma vez que caso a ordem das chaves for alterada, a comparação será errada. [Veja aqui](https://github.com/lffg/SOpt/blob/master/tags/javascript/order-json-stringify.js). Poderia até usar o `Array.prototype.sort`, mas acho que só iria criar complexidade adicional...

Comment: @LuizFelipe usa o metodo includes()... a ordem não interessa...

Comment: A ordem é levada em conta sim, já que você está verificando se o objeto inteiro (em forma de _string_) já existe. Como o output em string varia, de acordo com a ordem das propriedades, a filtragem é prejudicada. [Veja no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@lffg/SOpt-2019-12-10).

Comment: @LuizFelipe certo, nem tinha visto o link, não estava pensando nessa ordem...